# Vista Windows Scheduler task starts failing, and then never works again

Tags: windows, windows-vista, task-scheduler

I have a scheduler task setup to run every hour, to update a web server. It runs each hour correctly. But after a reboot, the task always starts to fail: The error is:

```
  Task Scheduler failed to start "\Website Refresh" task for user "myserver\Admin". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726.
```

The task requires admin privileges and is setup like this:

- "When running the task, use the following user account" (myserver\Admin)
- "Run whether user is logged on or not" (checked)
- "Do not store password" (unchecked)
- "Run with highest privileges" (checked)
- "Hidden" (unchecked)
- "Trigger" (daily at 12:00 AM ever day, after triggered repeat every 1 hour for a duration of 1 hour...")

This tasks fails the same way if I run it manually (using the RUN button in the task scheduler).

Once I go in as admin and reset the password on the task it starts work again. Until I reboot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to several forum posts I found, there seems to be a Vista problem with storing User credentials for the task scheduler.

Symptom (eventlog):

- Event ID: 101
- OP Code: 6619136
- Error Value: 2147943726

Possible Solution:

If the *"Run whether user is logged on or not"* option is used:

- check the box on "Do not store password"
- check "Run at highest privileges"
- make sure you got sufficient Admin rights for what your tasking.

Comment: I am already configured as indicated in the "possible solution", but it loses setting again after reboot.

Comment: According to your original question, you have the "Do not store password" box UNchecked.  Did you try it with it checked?

Comment: I think this is the key: check the box on "Do not store password"

Answer (score 1):

> "Trigger" (daily at 12:00 AM ever day,
>   after triggered repeat every 1 hour
>   for a duration of 1 hour...")

Doesn't this make it run only once a day? Duration should be 24 hours.

Comment: no, it runs hourly. But, in any case, I get the error even if I go and run it manually.